# Sync Excel and GoogleSheet

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, synchronization

I have a script to sync an excel file with a google sheet:

It works fine, but when I run it and the sheetname(s) already exist, then I get an error.
How can I fix this: Override or delete al existing sheets before executing the script?
I'm trying to post the code but I get always an error.

```
// Importing all sheets from Excel to Google Sheets
function importAllExcelSheets() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Mijn Bestand.xlsm");

  // Replace NAAM_VAN_HET_EXCEL_BESTAND.xlsx with the exact name of your Excel file.
  if (file.hasNext()) {
    var excelFile = file.next();
    var blob = excelFile.getBlob();
    var resource = {
      title: "[Google Sheets] " + excelFile.getName(),
      mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
    };
    var newFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob);
    var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newFile.id);
    var sheets = newSpreadsheet.getSheets();

    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
      var newSheet = sheets[i];
      var data = newSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      var sheetName = newSheet.getName();
      var targetSheet = sheet.copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet());
      targetSheet.setName(sheetName);
      targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
    }

    Browser.msgBox("Alle sheets uit het Excel-bestand zijn succesvol geïmporteerd.");
  } else {
    Browser.msgBox("Excel-bestand niet gevonden. Zorg ervoor dat het bestand bestaat en dat de naam correct is gespeld.");
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that in your question when you provide your current script, it will help think of your current issue and your question in `but when I run it and the sheetname(s) already exist, then I get an error. How can I fix this`.

Comment: I'm sure you can check (with a script) if the sheet with the same name exists already and delete (or rename) it. But the actual solution depends on what your script looks like.

Comment: In the mean while I found a script to delete the excisting sheets before importing. Tryed to upload the code again, but still not ok.

Comment: What do you mean _tried to upload the code_? You have to open the code with any text editor copy the text and paste it into your question inside the triple back quote marks ``` ```

Comment: Please share an [mcve].  We can be a lot more helpful if you produce a [mcve] that produces the problem.  Trying to make us guess at the problem is a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: - [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: // Importeren van alle sheets vanuit Excel naar Google Sheets
function importAllExcelSheets() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Mijn Bestand.xlsm"); // Vervang NAAM_VAN_HET_EXCEL_BESTAND.xlsx door de exacte naam van je Excel-bestand.
    if (file.hasNext()) {
    var excelFile = file.next();
    var blob = excelFile.getBlob();
    var resource = {
      title: "[Google Sheets] " + excelFile.getName(),
      mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS
    };

Comment: var newFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob);
    var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newFile.id);
        var sheets = newSpreadsheet.getSheets();
    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
      var newSheet = sheets[i];
      var data = newSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      var sheetName = newSheet.getName();
      var targetSheet = sheet.copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet());
      targetSheet.setName(sheetName);
      targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
    }

Comment: Browser.msgBox("Alle sheets uit het Excel-bestand zijn succesvol geïmporteerd.");
  } else {
    Browser.msgBox("Excel-bestand niet gevonden. Zorg ervoor dat het bestand bestaat en dat de naam correct is gespeld.");
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace the line:

```
targetSheet.setName(sheetName);
```

with:

```
try { targetSheet.setName(sheetName) } catch(e) {}
```

It won't rename the sheet if the spreadsheet already has the given name.

Alternatively you can try to get the sheet with the same name and rename it. Something like this:

```
try {
  var temp_sheet = newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  temp_sheet.setName(temp_sheet.getName() + "#");
} catch(e) {}
```

**Update**

You can try to remove the sheet with name `sheetName` before you add the new sheet:

```
try {
  var sheet_to_remove = newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  newSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheet_to_remove);
} catch(e) {}
```

Note: probably it won't delete the sheet if there's only one sheet in the spreadsheet. If it's your case, probably it makes sense to combine the both approaches:

- first try to get the sheet with the same name and rename it
- copy a new sheet
- try to remove the renamed sheet

Something like this:

```
var sheet_to_delete = newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
if (sheet_to_delete != null) sheet_to_delete.setName(sheetName + "#");

// here is the part of your code to copy the data from your .xls

if (sheet_to_delete != null) newSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheet_to_delete);
```

**Update 2**

Try to replace the lines:

```
for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
  var newSheet = sheets[i];
  var data = newSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var sheetName = newSheet.getName();
  var targetSheet = sheet.copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet());
  targetSheet.setName(sheetName);
  targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

with:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // the target spreadsheet

for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {

  // get the name of the copied sheet from the source spreadsheet
  var sheetName = sheets[i].getName();

  // copy the sheet from the source spreadsheet to the target one
  // it copies the sheet a whole with its formatting, not just data from the cells
  // the copy `targetSheet` gets some default name 'Copy of ...'
  var targetSheet = sheets[i].copyTo(ss);

  // on the target spreadsheet try to get the old sheet with the name `sheetName`
  var old_sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);    

  // if there is the sheet, delete it
  if (old_sheet != null) ss.deleteSheet(old_sheet);

  // assign to the copied sheet the proper name instead of the default one
  targetSheet.setName(sheetName);
}
```

And if you want to remove the temporary (?) file `[Google Sheets] Mijn Bestand.xlsm` it makes sense to add after the loop the line:

```
Drive.Files.trash(newFile.getId());
```

It will put the file into the trash bin automatically.

Comment: Both solutions are adding all the sheets with name copy of the existing sheets. I want to replace them, not making a copy. That is why I tried the option to delete first the existing files, before adding the new sheets.

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand your workflow. If you mean to try to remove the old sheet with the same name see the update to my answer.

Comment: My data in the excel sheets are updated daily. So it rather be a refresh of thé data in googlesheet. Also because I want to keep thé formatting off cells in thé Google sheets (or keeping thé formatting of cells from the excel of possible).

Comment: Sorry. It still eludes me what you're trying to do and what's going wrong. Try to describe step by step: (1) what you have, (2) what you're doing, and (3) what the desired result should look like (with screenshots, perhaps). You can add this info in your answer.

Comment: I'm trying to embed data from excel file in a webpage. But when I do that from excel, everyone can see the url and download the whole file. There is a restriction possible but it only works in Onedrive for business. With GoogleSheets it can be done.  So I'm looking for a way to sync excel and googlesheets. The excel file with several sheets (linked to MS Access) is updated weekly and concerns statistics from our cycling group (who participated, kilometers, wheather......)

Comment: _to sync excel and googlesheets_ — to replace all the sheets of the existing spreadsheet with the sheets of the existing .xls file? Or to add the new sheets from .xls. Or both? Or replace (or add?) some cells (or columns? rows?) within existing sheets of the spreadsheet? Please add step by the step description in your question: 1) I have this and this... 2) I want to make my script do this and this... 3) but in this case it does this..., etc.

Comment: 1. I have an excel file called statistics. There are 5 or 6 sheets in it witch get data from a connected access file. Those data change regularly.   2. The script above syncs those data with a googlesheet,. That sheet is used to embed data in a webpage. 3. But with the code above the formatting off cells (color, specific things....) is not included. 4. So I'm looking for a way to replace the existing data with the new data in the googlesheets and keeping the formatting of the sheets. I know there are payed solutions for this, but my project is on a small scale for my friends bikers.

Comment: Well. Try my second update. It works fine on my test files.

Comment: I tried your second update, but then everytime I run it then there is a copy of 1 sheet added and then I get an error: there is already sheet with name Grafieken, gif it another name.

Comment: Maybe you can send the whole code?

Comment: Here is the text file with the code inside: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14vt4wn0DTnr4ucPYgfu7_l20or38dX3C/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That's it I think. Can you explain what it does? It seems to add sheets and then delete some.

Comment: I've just added the comments into my last snippet. Yes, it removes old sheets from the target spreadsheet if they have the same names as copied sheets in the source spreadsheet.